# Define Typescript interface with using constant names as keys

Tags: typescript, constants

I am trying to define an interface in TypeScript that uses key names from a constant object. However, I am encountering an issue where I am getting the following error:

Initializer type {[p: string]: string | number} is not assignable to variable type Test

Here is the code I am working with:

```
const KEYS: Record<string, string> = {
  KEY1: 'hello',
  KEY2: 'world'
}

interface Test {
  [KEYS.KEY1]: string;
  [KEYS.KEY2]: number;
}

const testData: Test = {
  [KEYS.KEY1]: 'javascript',
  [KEYS.KEY2]: 42,
}
```

Is there a way for me to use constants to define key names in an interface in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you remove the `Record<string, string>` type annotation and add `as const` so that the keys become compile-time constants (because TypeScript works with compile-time information, not runtime information):

```typescript
const KEYS = {
    KEY1: "hello",
    KEY2: "world",
} as const;
```

Then the rest of your code works.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoGUYF4YG8CwAoGQ+ZARgC4YAiACwFMAbekSgGnyOKQCYLKB3EACd6AE1b4AvjACGEGKEhQA3PnwBLMFFqCAZtOC0YAFVrRs7IgG1EqAHQ2SAXQrRBGgOYqCVmynvIuZxgwAFcAWwAjbS8JVTwFMy1oABFpKGkKEzNMXG9Ca2Q-ByDKACtpADdZYDcAByhxPJgCuxtAigAWLjY8CS98BJB6WlsmdwAKJKhU9Jai0kcASi9B4dGQCamZ6Tn-biWlIA)