# Define TypeScript type of object whose keys are constants

Tags: typescript

My question is similar to [Define Typescript interface with using constant names as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783581/define-typescript-interface-with-using-constant-names-as-keys) but is a little bit different.

I start off with the same type of object whose keys are constants

```js
const KEYS = {
  KEY1: 'hello',
  KEY2: 'world'
} as const;
```

But instead of strings, I have objects as values. So in my code I want to know what *type* of object is in that key. (All of the object types are the same.) So for example, I really want something like:

```js
const KEYS : {const: string} {
  KEY1: 'hello',
  KEY2: 'world'
} as const;
```

Is there some way to do this? I keep getting error ts2353 because the const doesn't appear properly. If possible, I would like a 1 line solution (aka, what do I need to replace `const: string` with to make this work) because I have almost 200 keys, so I'd prefer not rewriting each const individually as a type.

[According to jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78247614/define-typescript-type-of-object-whose-keys-are-constants#comment137949156_78247614), it sounds like I want something like an "index signature"? I tried a few different types and nothing seems to work so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you just looking for an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of the form `{[k: string]: string}`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxEZBW)? If so I'll write an answer (or find a dupe target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for. All the ones I'm trying don't seem to be working so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, yeah that seems to be working now. Not sure why it wasn't working before because I swear I had tried it. Not sure if the question is worth it with all the downvotes anymore, but if you want to post an answer and I'll accept it. At least you'll get points.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get the chance. I don’t know what’s going on with the downvotes either (I rarely downvote; I only do it when there’s a problem that persists after comments)  Mentioning votes in the question is unlikely to improve matters, though.

Comment: Sounsd good. I'll remove it from the edit. I'm just confused as it's the second question I keep getting downvoted on and I don't understand why. Not sure if it's the way I'm asking, but anyway. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), since "you don't know all the names of a type's properties ahead of time, but you do know the shape of the values." Instead of `{const: string}` you're looking for `{[k: string]: string}`, which means "every property with key `k` of type `string` will have a value of type `string`". You can also write that as `Record<string, string>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

Given that you're using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) you presumably don't want to make the compiler actually *forget* about the known keys `KEY1` and `KEY2` or the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"hello"` and `"world"`. So while you *could* write

```
const KEYS: { [k: string]: string } = {
  KEY1: 'hello',
  KEY2: 'world'
} as const;
```

and [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `KEYS` as having that index signature type, it's not what you want.  Instead it looks like you just want to make sure that `KEYS` *satisfies* that index signature type without *widening* it to that type.  If so then you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const KEYS = {
  KEY1: 'hello',
  KEY2: 'world'
} as const satisfies { [k: string]: string };
```

That compiles without changing the inferred type of `KEYS`, but will still catch an error if you mistakenly make one of the properties have a bad value:

```
const KEYS = {
  KEY1: 'hello',
  KEY2: 123 // error!
  //~~ <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
} as const satisfies { [k: string]: string };
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoGUYF4YG8BQN7ICMAXDAOQAWApgDY0hkA0eBSATKWQO4gBONAEzI4AvjACGEGKEiwI4qAEsIAM0VUpWGAG0A1qWi9FYAOYBdA1COmYIgNw4cM6DABCAQQAiiVBmwsfEnJqOgZmfB8OGEI2AGYYAHoEmCpeXj4AQhYkgD8cmAAeAFoimAAVAE8ABypyMABXAFsAI1SyGGUYMBBYSQhFEzBxZppaqBAYKGraskNjEzIAOlEJKWc5BWU1DWwdfRg50wsDq3nbOyA)